# Keep the message ID in the text field so I can reply to a message with an upload

Tags: feature-request, chat

When I click the arrow icon to start a reply to a chat message, the text field is prepended with a colon followed by the message ID. This also works even if you've entered something in the text field, so

```
Replying to somebody
```

becomes

```
:1234567 Replying to somebody
```

But since an image upload will submit immediately, I have to start the reply before uploading.

But that doesn't work either. The message ID that's prepended ends up being erased and replaced with the image URL before the upload submits. I have to edit to include the message ID to turn it into a reply, and since editing a message with a onebox causes the onebox to reload, it can get distracting.

Can we please preserve the message ID so

```
:6059107
```

becomes

```
:6059107 https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzFM3.png
```

and not

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzFM3.png
```

instead so I don't have to edit it or upload it separately?

**EDIT [11/20]:** just found out that the upload button is totally disabled when the field isn't empty now. I guess it's to stop any message being completely replaced with the upload URL, so perhaps seeing it from that perspective, it's a good thing. It doesn't exactly help matters here, though.

Comment: Awww, I was hoping that was a link to an actual image. Thoroughly disappointed...

Comment: @animuson: Awww. There, I fixed it. Note that the message ID points to a real message in the Teachers' Lounge, but non-mods won't be able to see it anyway... right?

Comment: @animuson: Duh, I think I may have misread your comment, but whatever :P

Comment: Did you really just edit this like six times, or did the live refresh go haywire? Also, unless this gets implemented soon I'm going to add it to [the userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/2105/se-chat-modifications-keyboard-navigation-and-commands-for-chat), because this annoys me so much.

Comment: @Tim Stone: Uh oh. Ninja edits not so ninja anymore.

Comment: I see everything o_o

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, this has always bugged me...so I finally added it to the [chat userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2105/se-chat-modifications-keyboard-navigation-and-commands-for-chat) until such a time that it's implemented natively. As long as the input only contains the reply ID, the userscript will make sure that image is submitted as an explicit reply.

Currently this works fine for cases where you click a reply link, but I do still have to work around the issue where the button gets disabled if you subsequently trigger key events in the input field.